# Get Joomla jdoc in PHP?

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

I am very new to Joomla, and I am trying to get the output of a `<jdoc:include />` tag in PHP before the page is rendered.

My menu is included like this: `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="main menu" />`
I am trying to count the `<li>` tags within the main menu. I have it setup like this:

```
$str = <<< HTML
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="main menu" />
HTML;
$count = substr_count($str, '<li>');
echo $count;
echo $str;
```

The menu echoes like normal, but `$count` is always 0, like it hasn't parsed yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<jdoc:include type="modules" name="main menu" />` is used to include the module in "main menu" position.li tag is in modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php page

Answer (score 1):

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="main menu" />
```

Above line means that your main manu is included as a Joomla module.

If you are to count you will have to render the module 1st.

method 1

```
$document   = &JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer   = $document->loadRenderer('module');
$params   = array('style'=>$style);
$result = $renderer->render(JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_main_menu'), $params);
```

else try this code to render

method 2

```
$module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_module');
$result = JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
```

Let's assume that your main menu module name is mod_main_menu.

Then try to count like below.

```
$count = substr_count($result, '<li>');
echo $count;
```

Comment: Both methods do not return anything for `$result`. I have ended up using jQuery to count them by adding an ID tag to the UL in the Joomla backend.

Comment: You can not be empty unless you don't type the module name correctly

Comment: I have used jQuery to get what I needed. I couldn't render it with PHP.